# Blazor-server-side can't see GLTF files

Tags: iis, .net-core, blazor-server-side

i have my blazor app hosted on azure with iis

got some GLTF file i want to access with three.js but its like my app can't see any of my GLTF files.

i have added a virtual directory inside my blazor app in IIS manager. (E://Output) is added inside IIS as a virtual folder next to wwwroot

if i go to https://xxxxx.com/output/637650602249582109_Output/VisData/room.bin (this file exist fine, and it will start downloading it)

if i go to https://xxxxx.com/output/637650602249582109_Output/VisData/scene.gltf
it gives me a 404 ..

i have tried to add this in my startup:

```
app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
            {
                ServeUnknownFileTypes = true,
                DefaultContentType = "text/plain"
            });
```

it kinda helped with files i included in the projects wwwroot folder (wwwroot/VisData/scene.gltf)

https://xxxxx.com/VisData/scene.gltf

But what am I doing wrong with the files i have includes thru a virtual drive?

Comment: renaming the file to scene.json it will serve it no problem.

Comment: Sonny Hansen  - renaming the gltf file "scene.gltf" to "scene.json" definitely solved the problem, for some reason when adding gltf MIME type to IIS it resolves with error 500. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add the GLTF file extension `.gltf` to your IIS, `.bin` is already mapped:

[image: IIS_File_Extensions]

Comment: This made my file being served.. I was so sure i already did this, but i guess not.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by dependency injection, just add the following to your `Program.cs`.

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles;


...


builder.Services.Configure<StaticFileOptions>(options =>
{
    options.ContentTypeProvider = new FileExtensionContentTypeProvider
    {
        Mappings =
        {
            [".gltf"] = "model/gltf+json",
            [".glb"] = "model/gltf-binary",
            [".bin"] = "application/octet-stream"
        }
    };
});
```

Full docs with an alternative option:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-6.0#blazor-server-file-mappings-and-static-file-options